# Hiding some configurable attribute in the front-end - magento

Tags: attributes, hide, magento-1.7, configurable-product

Please help...anyone

I have a problem with hiding some configurable attributes:

These are my configurable attributes at the back-end:

- Shape/Type
- Grit & Colour
- Shank
- Items pack
- Diameter
- Supplier

My client wants to hide the "Manufacturer" attribute on the front-end
but wants to import the supplier at the back-end.

Please see the website I am working:

http://ridental.com.au/newsite/polishers.html/

I managed to hide it from front-end by just adding some if statement 
like this: in the `app\design\frontend\default\MYTEMPLATE\template\catalog\product\view\type\options\configurable.phtml`

```
<?php
$_product    = $this->getProduct();
$_attributes = Mage::helper('core')->decorateArray($this->getAllowAttributes());
?>
<?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && count($_attributes)):?>
<dl class="outer">
<dl class="inner">
<?php foreach($_attributes as $_attribute): ?>
<?php $attCode =   $_attribute->getProductAttribute()->getFrontend()->getAttribute()->getAttributeCode(); ?>

   <?php if($attCode != "manufacturer"):?>
    <div class="dtdd-wrapper<?php if ($_attribute->decoratedIsLast){echo " last";}?>">
    <dt><label class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $_attribute->getLabel() ?></label></dt>
    <dd<?php if ($_attribute->decoratedIsLast){?> class="last"<?php }?>>
        <div class="input-box">
            <select name="super_attribute[<?php echo $_attribute->getAttributeId() ?>]" id="attribute<?php echo $_attribute->getAttributeId() ?>" class="required-entry super-attribute-select">
                <option><?php echo $this->__('Choose an Option...') ?></option>
              </select>
    </div>
    </dd>
    </div>
  <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</dl>
</dl>
<script type="text/javascript">
    [b]var spConfig = new Product.Config(<?php echo $this->getJsonConfig() ?>);[/b]
</script>
```

The Manufacturer will not be displayed on the front-end.

But when I click Add to Cart button I got the error:

*Please specify the product's option(s).*

I noticed that in:

`var spConfig = new Product.Config(<?php echo $this->getJsonConfig()`

It is still referring to the attribute "supplier" and waiting for the user response to choose Manufacturer in the drop down.

that's why I get the error: Please specify the product's option(s).

**My question:**

Is it possible to filter the function `getJsonConfig()`? 
   let say not include the:

if  ($attributecode != 'manufacturer'){
       do some stuff.....
    }

I copied a local version of this function and now found in: `app\code\local\Mage\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable.php`

Please help...if anyone accomplished this kind of problem.
I tried extending `getJsonConfig()` to filter some attribute like "supplier" but to no avail.

Am I doing the right thing?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? The idea of the configurable attribute is to allow the user to chose this option. If you don't display it how will the system know which manufacturer variation is to be be used? If you can explain why you want to do this and what you are trying to achieve I may be able to help..

Answer (score 1):

Chances are, from what you are describing, you should remake the configurable product without using the "Supplier" attribute.

When you make a configurable product, the first screen that allows you to mark attributes with check boxes is meant to define what the configurable product will be *filtering*, the attributes will still be attached to the product information.